# How to map and manipulate JSON child elements to model properties (using JsonConvert)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, mapping

I am attempting to populate a model from JSON.  I'm using Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.

```
    HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlhere);
    httpWebRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("un", "pw");
    httpWebRequest.Method = "Get";
    httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
    Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(stream);
    string incomingItemAsJson = streamReader.ReadToEnd();    // should be the json response as a string

    MyObject myObject= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(incomingItemAsJson);
```

I'm struggling to access (and iterate through) child elements in the Json.

```
{
"field1": "blah blah",
"field2": "blah blah",
"field3": [(2)
    {
    "field3Item1Id": "xxx",
    "field3Item1Value": "Goo"
    },-
    {
    "field3Item2Id": "xxx",
    "field3Item2Value": "Foo"
    }-
    ],-
"field4": {
    "field4Id": xxx,
    "field4Value": "Moo"
    }-
}
```

I'd like to map this info to a model, like so:

```
public class MyObject 
{
    public string field1 {get;set;}  //blah blah
    public string field2 {get;set;}  //blah blah
    public string field3 {get;set;}  //Goo, Foo
    public string field4 {get;set;}  //Moo
}
```

Field1 and field2 are being assigned to string properties in MyObject - no problem there.

**My Questions:**

*Field3*

How can I concatenate the Value part of each item into a single string, like this: "Goo, Foo"?

*Field4*

There will only ever be one child element in field4.

Is there a simple way to extract only the Value part and map it to a string property in MyObject?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Newton's JSON just creates mapping simply, and if you don't have similar structured objects in this case, it may not be possible to change the structure of JSON because it might be from other source, so you can change your Model class like..

```
public class MyObject 
{
    public string field1 {get;set;}  
    public string field2 {get;set;}  
    public Dictionary<string, string> field3 {get;set;}
    public Dictionary<string, string> field4 {get;set;}
}
```

That should do the trick...

Comment: Dictionary will make it flexible enough to handle one or mode objects in you field3 and field4...

Comment: Sorry for the delay in getting back on this one. This is the approach I used in the end - thank you very much :)